# How would you characterize the gerunds in these cases?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-clauses

I have these sentences / phrases and am trying to figure out how to characterize the gerunds is each:

(a) First on Clark’s list is Japan’s well-known propensity for **putting** the group before the self, and by extension **following** orders from one’s superiors.

(b) Honesty in **dealing** with others

(c) Soon after **arriving** in Japan, when I was still getting used to **commuting** by train instead of car, I left my bag on the Yamanote Line.

I can see that (a) somehow modifies the subject ("propensity (Sb) *for putting*... is first (V)"), but I am confused about the terminology. (b) is not even a full sentence. As about (c), both clauses are clearly subordinate, but again, I can't seem to figure out just what to say about these gerunds. Can you help me out?

Comment: The gerund-participial clauses are **complement** of the prepositions "for", "in" and "after"  and "to". "Propensity" is not a subject; it's predicative complement of "be" ("is"). The PPs in (a) (b) and the second one in (c) are complements of "propensity", "honesty" and "used". The first PP in (c) is a temporal adjunct.

Comment: Having a *propensity **for doing*** something is just [a less common alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=propensity+to+do%2Cpropensity+for+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpropensity%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpropensity%20for%20doing%3B%2Cc0) to having a *propensity **to do*** it. In your first example, the "verby" nature of the gerund *(**putting**)* can be seen by the fact that it takes an "object" *(**the group**)*.

Comment: Thank you both.